# Trigger UITextView tap event despite Tap Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm simulating an iBooks style text reader in an app I'm building. I have a UITextView that displays un-editable but selectable content, and I have a Tap Gesture Recognizer on it that makes various buttons on UIViews show or hide on tap. Because of this, however, tapping the UITextView doesn't trigger the normal tap behavior of a selectable UITextView (Ex: if text is selected, tapping outside of the selected text doesn't unselect it, it just makes the UIViews show/hide). I also have a UIPickerView, and the UITextView takes up the whole screen, so tapping outside of the UIPickerView triggers the Tap Gesture event and doesn't close the picker.

Is there any way that I can make it so tapping the UITextView triggers both the Tap Gesture Recognizer and the normal UITextView tap behavior? Or is there a better way to navigate this problem? Thanks so much!